# How to prove this given factor of standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In deriving the explicit expression for E(y|x) of a Tobit model, we need to derive 1) Pr(y>0|x); 2)E(y|x,y>0).

The Tobit model is basically:
$$y=max(0,x\beta+u)$$
$$u|x\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$
Hence, provided that $y*=x\beta+u$
$y=max(0,y*)$ for simplicity

To derive $E(y|x)$, it is not difficult to understand the first step, which is:
$$E(y|x)=Pr(y=0|x)*0+Pr(y>0|x)*E(y|x,y>0)$$
But to derive $$E(y|x,y>0)$$
The following fact is given:
if $Z \sim N(0,1)$,
$$E[Z|Z>c]=\frac{\phi(c)}{1-\Phi(c)}$$

Could someone explain how this fact is derived? In our lecture slide this fact is taken as given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all $$E[Z|A] = \frac{E[\mathbf{1}_A Z]}{P(A)}$$
Using this we get:
\begin{align}
E[Z|Z>c]= \frac{E[\mathbf{1}_{Z>c}Z]}{P(Z>c)} = \frac{E[\mathbf{1}_{Z>c}Z]}{1-\Phi(c)}
\end{align}
Where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution. Let's calculate $E[Z\mathbf{1}_{Z>c}]$. That is just (figure out why yourself):
\begin{align}
E[Z\mathbf{1}_{Z>c}] = \int^\infty_c z\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz
\end{align}
Substitute $x=z^2/2$ so that $dx=zdz$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes!